# JBoss dumping access logs in ~/logs

Tags: jboss

I have a weird problem where for a single application, JBoss (EAP 6.0.0) seems to be dumping access logs in my home dir at `~/logs`. This is annoying to say the least.

My web application's `jboss-web.xml` file seems normal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 2.4//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_0.dtd">

<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/moore</context-root>

    <!-- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve  -->
    <valve>
        <class-name>org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve</class-name>
        <param>
            <param-name>prefix</param-name>
            <param-value>access_log_moore_</param-value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <param-name>suffix</param-name>
            <param-value>.log</param-value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <param-name>pattern</param-name>
            <param-value>%h %A %l %u %t "%r" %s %b %T %I "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"</param-value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <param-name>resolveHosts</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <param-name>fileDateFormat</param-name>
            <param-value>yyyy-MM-dd-HH</param-value>
        </param>
    </valve>

</jboss-web>
```

I can't seem to find anywhere that's telling it to dump logs in `~/logs` and all other web applications log fine to the JBoss log directory. How can I debug where the misconfiguration is and get these logs back to the JBoss log directory?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach to configure access logs in JBoss EAP 6.x is add this in `domain:web` subsystem.
**Eg:**

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.4" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
        <access-log pattern="%h %A %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b %T %I  &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot;" prefix="access_log_moore_" rotate="true">
            <directory path="." relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" />
        </access-log>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

See also: [JBoss EAP 6.0.1 Model Reference](http://wildscribe.github.io/JBoss%20EAP/6.0.1/subsystem/web/virtual-server/access-log/configuration/index.html)

However if you need/want use a valve configuration inside application with `jboss-web.xml` you must add attribute `directory` in your configuration with absolute path to log directory.

**Eg:**

```
<jboss-web>
   <context-root>/moore</context-root>
   <valve>
        <!-- ...  -->
        <param>
            <param-name>directory</param-name>
            <param-value>/path/to/jboss/log/dir</param-value>
        </param>
    </valve>
</jboss-web>
```

> ```
> directory
> ```
>
> Absolute or relative pathname of a directory in which log files
>   created by this valve will be placed. If a relative path is specified,
>   it is interpreted as relative to `$CATALINA_HOME`. If no directory
>   attribute is specified, the default value is "logs" (relative to
>   `$CATALINA_HOME`).

In JBoss 7/EAP 6  `$CATALINA_HOME` is not set and the log is created in `~/logs` (In your case).

Ref: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/config/valve.html

I hope this help.